# Is there a way to use application insights without an Azure subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I know my question sounds weird and probably the simple answer is "No".
However, given that the list of good and useful things which the Application Insights SDK does, I was wondering if there is a way to make it log to something on-prem like a key-value pair database running on-prem.

Comment: If you have a valid `InstrumentalKey` which is more enough to send any logs into App insights Irrespective of the platform(on-prem/Cloud)

Comment: I think the question was how to use AI SDK and save data locally...

Comment: And, yes, I really want to use App Insights locally. I have some customers who are dreadful of the cloud and they have their reasons. So, having used App Insights and found it useful, I was wondering if we can do something so it starts logging to something sitting locally.

Answer (score 9):

Eventflow might do the trick.
https://github.com/Azure/diagnostics-eventflow

It supports Application Insights as input and outputs like ElasticSearch, any Http etc. So you could host ES locally/on-prem, use Application Insights SDK to collect data, send it to Eventflow, and have it sent to local/on-prem ES cluster.

Or Alternatively, you can implement your own `ITelemetryChannel` to send data to any targets.

Comment: Thank you so much! Let me try this out.

Comment: I looked at the link you suggested and it would work for the server components. Is there a  way to do this with the Application Insights JS files?

Comment: You can override the endpoint to which SDK sends telemetry data to an end point you own/control in on-prem. Do the same for js sdk as well.